# Can't make a CSS @font-face rule if the font is not in the same folder as a CSS file

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to make a simple webpage with a digital clock and downloaded a "Digital" font for this.
It's working when I put font in the same folder as the CSS file, like this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('digital.ttf');
}
```

But I want to have a distinct "font" folder, then folder with font name and then font itself. How can I access this font then?
I tried like this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('../fonts/digital/digital.ttf');
}
```

And this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('/fonts/digital/digital.ttf');
}
```

And this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('fonts/digital/digital.ttf');
}
```

No effect.

Comment: Where is the fonts folder, relative to the CSS folder? Also, did you set a `<base>` in the document?

Comment: Look at the networking tab of your browser's developer tools. What URLs is the browser generating from these relative URLs?

Comment: A good way to do this is to place all the fonts in one folder, called `fonts`, then place in that subdirectories for each font. In those subdirectories, put all the files (`.ttf`, `.svg` etc...) and use `@font-face` in a stylesheet in the subdirectory. They you can link with `@import` into another stylesheet, like `main.css`.

Comment: Font,css and my directory structure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4paDjUAakEUT1oteVJtdHF1WnM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It is connected with permissions.
The font file itself had all the permissions necessary ('-rwxr-xr-x').
But the folder it was in had not! ('drwx------').
So I chmoded this folder with 755 and everything works now!

Thanks everybody for replies!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following directory structure

```
project
│   index.html
│
├───css
│       style.css
│
└───fonts
    └───digital
            digital.ttf
```

As you mentioned there is a distinct "font" folder which has another folder with the font name which ultimately has the font files. the style-sheet is in a separate folder and index file is in the project's root directory.

So in the above case you can put the following declaration in your **style.css** file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('../fonts/digital/digital.ttf');
}
```

and link that CSS file it to your **index.html** file

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

**OR**

---

Consider the following directory structure

```
project
│   index.html
|   style.css
│
└───fonts
    └───digital
            digital.ttf
```

Here, there is no separate folder for your CSS *(not recommended)*.

So in the above case you can put the following declaration in your **style.css** file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('fonts/digital/digital.ttf');
}
```

and link that CSS file it to your **index.html** file

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

**OR**

---

Consider the following directory structure

```
project
│   index.html
│
└───fonts
    └───digital
            digital.ttf
```

Here, there is no separate css file or folder *(not at all recommended)*.

you could include this in your **index.html** `<head>...</head>`section

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: Digital;
        src: url('fonts/digital/digital.ttf');
    }
</style>
```

---

***Based on the question I think you are looking for the first or second one.***

Comment: I have the first example of directory structure, but for some reason two dots is not working for me...I would think that the font file is corrupted but when I put it in the same folder as css file - it somehow works!

Comment: Could you possibly upload everything somewhere so that it can be examined? where did you get the fonts from?

Comment: It is the first font in the list

Comment: Font,css and my directory structure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4paDjUAakEUT1oteVJtdHF1WnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i guess you are messing *font name* and *font-file names*. I got it working [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/192824325/00_sandbox/30596594/project.zip)

Comment: Just saw your zip file. Is your clock.php `<link>` tag correct? just check, it should be `<link href="css/clock.css" rel="stylesheet">` and not `<link href="fonts/clock.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Digital;
  src: url('./fonts/digital/digital.ttf');
}
```

try this..

Comment: Give me an example of your file/folder directory.I mean youe css file or font file is in which folder??

Comment: Font,css and my directory structure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4paDjUAakEUT1oteVJtdHF1WnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3b2ZcTXh0r_YzhMN2JWaGM3bkU/view


here i have changed the body color white ..its working..

Comment: It's working ONLY when font is in the same folder as a stylesheet. You did exactly that :)

Comment: I was asked you  about  your file/folder directory..So plz provide the original directory of your project...

Comment: If you want to add a fonts folder https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3b2ZcTXh0r_QVNISmF0aUMyejg/view?usp=sharing..Just add 
`
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('fonts/digital.ttf');
}`

Answer (score -1):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Digital;
  src: url('../fonts/digital/digital.ttf');
}
```

just add ../ before your paths and it will work
because it will go out from css folder first then it will go inside the fonts folder.

folder structure should be like this

```
--css
--fonts
   |--digital
      |--digital.ttf
```

both folder will be on the same level

Comment: That's the second example in the question.

Comment: yeah this is the right way. check deeply why not it's working. but THIS IS THE RIGHT WAY :)

Comment: I almost agree: this is the right way *if the folders are arranged in the way that makes this work*. But we don't know the positional relationship of the folders.

Comment: once reload page and check my answer again. i edited.

Comment: You're making a mistake: you assuming your preferred folder layout is the "right way": that is subjective, and the question maybe subject to a folder structure defined by someone who thinks this is not the right way.